# Calculation when sending data through Mongoose to MongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

Im trying to calculate a users BMI and send it through to my MongoDB atlas db, the bmi will be calculated through the height and weight that users enter, I've set up a Mongoose Schema that set out the function but at this point my bmi is not showing on the post request, can anyone steer me in the right direction?

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const users = mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    first:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    last:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    occupation:String,
    profile:{
        age:{
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        sex:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        height:{
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        weight:{
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
//Issue is here. Trying to use the Schema to 'pre' calculate
        bmi:{
            type: Number,
            get: () =>{
                let BMI = weight/height ** 2
                return BMI
            },
            set: BMI => BMI,
            alias: 'bmi',

        },
        eyeColor: String,
        incomePM: Number,
        interestedIn: String
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', users);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `pre` middleware of mongoose,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const users = mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    first:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    last:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    occupation:String,
    profile:{
        age:{
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        sex:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        height:{
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        weight:{
            type: Number,
            required: true
        },
        bmi:{
            type: Number,
        },
        eyeColor: String,
        incomePM: Number,
        interestedIn: String
    }
})

users
 .pre('save', function(next){
  console.log(this.profile.weight);
  console.log(this.profile.height);
  this.profile.bmi = 
    (this.profile.weight/this.profile.height) ** 2;
  next();   
 });
module.exports = mongoose.model('users', users);
```

Comment: Got a response this time, but im getting an ERR_ASSEERTION now. 
"Cast to Number failed for value \"NaN\"

Comment: It might be because (weight / height) is resulting in a non-number value. Try logging `this.profile.weight` and `this.profile.height` in the default function. If it still throws the error

Comment: yea, it's still throwing an error, why would the (weight/height) result in a non-number?

Comment: if this.profile.height is 0 or undefined or null, that's why it might result in a non-number. Try logging, this.profile.weight and this.profilr.height in the `default` function

Comment: It logs undefined

Comment: Updated the answer, to use a middleware